# When do I need to protect a fruit tree from cold, and how do I do it?

Tags: fruit-trees, peaches, frost, protection

The last couple of weeks we had unusually warm weather in the Northeast -- several days had record warm temperatures. My pair of (two-year-old, 8' high) peach trees have buds earlier than usual. If it matters, the varieties are *Reliance* and *Red Haven*, both selected for hardiness.

The warm streak is ending abruptly: it will be 12°F on Monday night.

- Is this warm/cold transition going to prevent me from getting fruit this year?
- Is there anything I can do to protect them from the cold? I'm thinking about covering them, but two nights below 20°F and a day with a high of 32°F seems like a long time for a tarp to keep the chill off.

Comment: what stage are the buds? if the buds are just starting to swell, they might be okay at 12F.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless they have passed the stage of bud swelling, they should be okay at 12F (as discussed by [Clemson](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/peach/faq/what_temperatures_cause_cold_damage_to_peach_flower_buds.html) and [NCSU](http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/hort/hil/hil-713.html) extension).

Methods used to actively protect a tree from low temperatures work best under calm clear conditions. Under these conditions, an inversion layer occurs - this is a relatively stable cold air mass at the surface with warmer air above.

1. Cover with a blanket - helps to retain heat radiated from the earth surface
2. Spray a mist to create a fog - helps to retain heat radiated from the earth surface
3. Wind machine - helps to mix cold air at surface with warmer air above.
4. Irrigate - frozen water around the buds serve to insulate them from lower temperatures
5. Place heaters under the tree.

These are all described in more detail on the ["Freeze Protection Fact Sheet"](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/85-116.htm#freeze) published by Ontario Ministry of Agriculture, Food, and Rural Affairs. For more details on how to implement the irrigation method, see the [NCSU Guide to Deciding When to Start and Stop Irrigation
for Frost Protection of Fruit Crops by K.B. Perry](http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/hort/hil/hil-713.html).

Comment: Thanks for those pointers. I think they're at "red calyx", so I may use some percentage but not all the buds. I considered using a blanket/tarp, but the wind has been *really* strong. I think putting a giant sail on the trees would do more harm than the cold, and the wind pretty much makes mist impossible too. I guess I'm taking my chances...

Comment: @bstpierre sounds like the freeze you are having is not the type amenable to these methods. But temperatures experienced by a tree can be very different from temperatures predicted for a region. Good Luck! You could always wrap garbage bags around individual branches...

Comment: This answer http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3856/499 from @jdickson to use Christmas lights was too good not to be referred to.  Should work in cases where you have old inefficient lights and the frost is not below 5 deg F