# Protect apricot blossoms from frost

Tags: frost, apricots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I protect a peach tree from cold?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-can-i-protect-a-peach-tree-from-cold)

Popcorn is popping on my apricot tree, but there's supposed to be a frost tomorrow. The trees are marginal for the valley I live in as some years the frost damages the blossoms and makes for a year without a harvest.

Is there anything I can do to protect the blossoms?

Comment: [This answer from @David][1] is quite detailed and should cover everything


  [1]: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-can-i-protect-a-peach-tree-from-cold