# Protect flowering fruit trees from frost

Tags: fruit-trees, frost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I need to protect a fruit tree from cold, and how do I do it?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/when-do-i-need-to-protect-a-fruit-tree-from-cold-and-how-do-i-do-it)

We have several cherry trees and an apple tree in our back yard.  Due to the very warm March we had (in Minnesota), they are all covered in flowers.  In a few days, there is a chance of snow, and an overnight low of 26.

What do I need to do to protect them?

I saw [When do I need to protect a fruit tree from cold, and how do I do it?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3717/138), but I don't know if the difference between just starting to bud, and having flowers on them for a week or two is important.

Comment: Look very carefully at documents in the accepted answer on the linked question. If you read those documents (esp the one from [NCSU](http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/hort/hil/hil-713.html)) you will see that, for example, apples at full bloom will have 90% kill at 25°F. As kevinsky mentions, the protection techniques will be the same as in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial thought was to cover them with tarps if they aren't too big.  I like the suggestion in the question you linked to about placing heaters under the tree as well.

A quick search found [this site](http://www.gardenguides.com/68705-protect-orange-trees-frost.html) about protecting orange trees.  It suggests keeping the ground near the tree wet and wrapping the trunk with cardboard or cloth.

[This site](http://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/319/) has a fantastic suggestion - put Christmas lights on the trees and leave them on all night.

Those are some things to try.  I think anything you can do to raise the temperature around the tree a little bit is good whether there are flowers on it or not.