# How can I tell if frost damage has happened?

Tags: fruit-trees

This is a follow up to [Protect flowering fruit trees from frost](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3855/138)

Background: We have several fruit trees in our back yard.  They are in full bloom at the moment.  It was supposed to be pretty cold last night. (I don't know what the actual low temperature was here overnight.)

We had enough tarps and Christmas lights to cover some trees, but not others.  So, other than waiting several months, is there a way to tell if the uncovered trees were damaged by the cold?

Answer (score 5):

The flowers will simply fall off, or if they are past that point the fruit turns very dark, and becomes translucent, it will then darken and dry out... I assume you know by now, how did it go?

Comment: The flowers didn't fall off, and I none are translucent, although a bunch of dark.  But I'm not sure if it's just dark before the fruit shows up.  I do  see a few fruits that have green peeking through.  I'll add another comment in a few weeks - we'll see what the future holds.